# Calculate the angle to fit a rectangle within a given width

Tags: trigonometry

I am a JavaScript programmer, and I have a problem for which why knowledge of maths is insufficient (where did all of the high school trigonometry disappear???).

I am trying to find the formula in order to rotate a rectangle of given size so that it fits within a width that is smaller than the length of rectangle. The length and height of the rectangle are known, as is the width in which it must be rotated to fit. I have absolutely no idea where to start...

Here's an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve. The red rectangle should be rotated to the blue position:

[Diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8ofd.png)

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT**

Here is the solution in JavaScript if anyone comes across this from the Stack Overflow realm:

```
  let w = container.offsetWidth
  let h1 = element.offsetHeight
  let l1 = element.offsetWidth

  let atan = Math.atan(h / l) * (180 / Math.PI)
  let sqr = w / Math.sqrt(Math.pow(h, 2) + Math.pow(l, 2))
  let x = Math.asin(sqr) * (180 / Math.PI)
  let ? = x - atan
```

Comment: Hint: the distance between the two points of contact can be calculated with Pythagorean theorem: $d = \sqrt{l_b^2 + w_b^2}$ where $l_b$ and $w_b$ are the length and width of the blue box. What can you now say about the **sine** of the angle that you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From figure, $$\sin ?= \frac{w-x}{l} \\ \cos ? = \frac{x}{h}$$ and so $$l\sin ? + h\cos ? = w$$

By the [Harmonic Addition Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicAdditionTheorem.html), we get $$\sqrt{h^2+l^2} \sin\left( ?+\tan^{-1} \frac hl\right) = w \\ \implies ? =\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{h^2+l^2}}\right) -\tan^{-1} \frac hl $$

Comment: First time I see $?$ being the symbol of anything in mathematics ! At least, good sense of humor. And good answer $(\to +1)$. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sometimes you got to be a little quirky :) Cheers